# NHibernate enable lazy loading for single query

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm

In .hbm mapping file, i have the following setting:

```
<set name="Fields" table="Fields" lazy="false" cascade="all" inverse="false">
```

/.../

The lazy loading for this collection is globally **disabled**

Is it a way to "locally" **enable** lazy loading only for single Linq query?

The HBM mapping file must remains intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think it is achievable by LINQ, but you can use NHibernate's ICriteria to achieve what you want. An example could be like below.

```
ISession.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
        .SetFetchMode("Fields", FetchMode.Lazy)
        .List<Entity>();
```

More information about ICriteria can be found: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html